# Complex MySQL Query - Select Unique Records, Count, Insert and Delete

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new! New here, new with MySQL and PHP. And I'm trying to do a little something which has got me all baffled up. Please try and help me guys.

I have a table with some sample data as follows:

```
ID  NAME    ATTRIBUTE
1   John     123
2   Sean     654
3   John     987
4   Audrey   458
5   John     123
6   Audrey   589
7   Peter    257
8   Marc     125
9   Audrey   326
10  Stan     456
11  Carol    698
```

And here's a list of what I intend to do -

1. Select the first 6 records
2. Find Unique Names from the 6 selected records – Expected Result : 3 Unique Names (John, Sean & Audrey)
3. Find the Number of Attributes for each Unique Name from the Selected 6 records – Expected Result: John (3 attributes) , Sean (1 attribute) and Audrey (2 attributes).
4. Count the Number of identical attributes for each of the Unique name from the selected 6 records – Expected Result: Name=> John, Attribute=> 123, No. of Occurrence=> 2, Name=> John, Attribute=> 987, No. of Occurrence=> 1 etc.
5. From the above selections, insert data to a new database table (e.g. Unique Names) in the format:

   a. NameID (Not the same one as the last table, new id – auto generated), 
      b. Name

   And in another table (e.g. Attributes)

   a. ID(Auto Generated),
      b. Attribute, 
      c. NameID (should be the same as ID in the last) – this is for the relationship between the Unique Names and Attributes table)
      d. Occurrence (of each attribute for each unique name)
6. Once the new tables are filled with the data, I would like to Delete the top 6 selected record from the first table from where they are collected. (The Top Table)

Can someone help me with the MySQL queries and supporting PHP codes for this one. Also, I would like to know the best and fastest possible way to query the MySQL for the above if I have millions of data in the tables.

Comment: `LIMIT`, `DISTINCT`/`GROUP BY`, `COUNT` & `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(DISTINCT`,`INSERT INTO`, `DELETE`, and maybe either read a introduction to SQL, or pay someone to do the work for you.

Comment: No it is not my homework, just trying to learn something myself.

Comment: I'm quite confident this is homework and I have taged it as such.

Comment: FYI - It's OK to have homework questions, but only if you are honest about it _and_ do some preliminary work.

Comment: Wow, is it my writing or what? This is my first ever question in StackOverflow and all I get is misunderstanding??

Comment: Guys this is NOT a homework, I dont study anywhere, im done with schools, just trying to learn myself!!! Sorry if I made a wrong post in the wrong place!!!

Comment: @Ranadeep: So, you agree, it is homework for self-study :)

Comment: Try adding a few lines of the code you tried and then you'll get feedback.

Comment: Thanks ypercube, at least your feedback is of some help. I will surely try and post here.

Comment: It's also common practice not to ask too many questions in the same post. You can for example, edit your post and add at the end; **"I have done this code (<code goes here>), it solves my problem up to q.2 but I'm stuck on q.3 and q.4, how do I solve it?"**  Then, when one of the answer seems OK, you can accept it as most useful. And then, if you have problems solving q.5, make a new post.

Comment: @ypercube: I get that, thanks. Working on the code, will edit it and post here soon. But with the -2 votes, this question is down to 8600 page, will someone ever find and answer it? I will try nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:

```
SELECT t.id,  t.name,t.attribute FROM t LIMIT 6
```

Question 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.name FROM (SELECT t.id, t.name, t.attribute FROM t LIMIT 6) t
```

Question 3:

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(t.attribute) AS number_of_attributes FROM(SELECT t.id, t.name, t.attribute FROM t LIMIT 6) t
GROUP BY t.name
ORDER BY number_of_attributes desc
```

Question 4:

```
SELECT t.name, t.attribute, COUNT(t.attribute) AS Appears FROM (SELECT t.id, t.name, t.attribute FROM t LIMIT 6) t
GROUP BY t.name,t.attribute
ORDER BY Appears desc
```

Question 5:
First part: Must be done in 2 steps, first select the unique names-from the top 6 first selected-, then add the `auto_increment` column:

```
CREATE TABLE unique_names SELECT DISTINCT t.name FROM t

ALTER TABLE unique_names ADD name_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST
```

Second part: the same as the first one, but in this case to get the id we join with the table created in the first part of this step, and then we add the `auto_increment` column

```
CREATE TABLE attributes SELECT t.attribute,un.name_id FROM t INNER JOIN unique_names un ON t.name=un.name

ALTER TABLE attributes ADD id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST
```

Question 6:

```
DELETE FROM t LIMIT 6
```

In this case I used `t` as the original table name